# Avoid down-casting value along parallel hierarchies

Tags: c++, downcast

I have two class hierarchies:

```
BaseUnit <- S1Unit , BaseUnit <- S2Unit, ..S3Unit, S4Unit
```

and

```
Base <- S1 , Base <- S2
```

In `Base` I stored the unit's value.

```
class Base {
  protected: BaseUnit unit; // actually this is an upcast of S1Unit, S2Unit
  // of course I do several things with unit on methods of Base 
}
```

which is based on S1Unit, S2Unit ..

```
S1::S1(S1Unit s1unit) : unit(s1unit) { .. }
```

However, if I now would like to return the specialized unit in S1, how would I best do this?

```
S1Unit S1::getUnit() const { return this->unit; /* how to cast down? */ }
```

I could implement `S1Unit` a constructor of `BaseUnit` `S1Unit::S1Unit(BaseUnit)` which works fine, but this kind of downcast copy constructor somehow is not very nice. All answers I have checked show examples using pointers.

**What would be a better solution? Any alternatives?**

Comment: `BaseUnit <- S1Unit , BaseUnit <- S2Unit, ..S3Unit, S4Unit` - I cannot parse this syntax.

Comment: The member `Base::unit` is nothing but a `BaseUnit`. You can't cast it down to anything because it's not anything else. If you want polymorphism, you need to use pointers or references.

Comment: Means S1Unit is derived from BaseUnit.

Comment: And what about the rest of it? They're all inherited from `BaseUnit`?

Comment: Maybe you should explain this again. Just start from the beginning and write it using other words and flow. :) I didn't understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functionality that differs between your classes should be exposed via [virtual functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function).

Then, you don't need to cast down the object and you can just return `unit`.  The member functions called will be the correct ones for the objects you've created.